# White Shadow in PNG when being exported

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am getting a shadow-shaped whites around my shadows in the image when exporting it to PNG-24 using 'Save for Web' option. I tried using other file formats aside from PNG-24 like PNG-8 and GIF but the white shadows still exist. Please see this image:
[image]

I am using Adobe Illustrator CS6. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jayson. This problem comes from the shadow. It is made with ellipse filled with gradient. From window>gradient you will see the gradient tab. You will see the two colors- in your case white and dark brown fading to each other. Click on the white color and you will see that there is an option to reduce it's opacity. Make it 0% and then export as PNG. This should solve your problem. Cheers ;))

Answer (score 0):

When 'saving for web', use the transparency dropdown to change it to diffusion.

Comment: When saving as PNG-24 (as the OP wants) the transparency is 8-bit and there is no "transparency dropdown". This is only avaliable in PNG-8 which has 1-bit transparency. It *should* be possible to save this image as PNG-24 with smooth transparent shadows.